# Redirect all URLs to main domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all my URL's to www.domain.com

```
www.domain.com/site-1 must redirect to www.domain.com
www.domain.com/site-2 must redirect to www.domain.com
a.s.o
```

I tried:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But when doing this I get redirected to: http://domain.com/index.php which is a a white page instead of the homepage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . http://www.mydomain.co.uk/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but the page is loading and loading and loading when adding your rewrite rule and the homepage never pops up...

Comment: Do you have other rules also?

Comment: I had but deleted them all and only put in
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . /? [R=301,L]

Comment: it does not load modules, stylesheet etc... only menu text and text when adding your rewriterule

Comment: ok for css/js issues just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: It works now - instead of your solution I put my domain see in the Update of my original thread - thanks for your help!

Comment: `RewriteRule http://www.mydomain.co.uk/? [R=301,L]` is has bad syntax. It should be: `RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/? [R=301,L]` (see my update in answer)

Comment: Hi - now I just tried it again and it does not work. Not mine and not yours :(

Comment: Did you not write: `It works now`? How was it working before and not working now?

Comment: Yes I did but it does not now.

With both of your suggestions I get a white page again.

Comment: It is Joomla 3.2 but that should not make a difference should it?

Comment: Yes it does make a difference. Make sure `RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/? [R=301,L]` is just below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: It is but when I add your code I get: The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: No again not loading stylesheets and anything...there must be a solution that does load them...